# Python, how do I retrieve the data in my list? this confuses me

Tags: python, mysql

```
    crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM tblmob")
    res = crsr.fetchall()

    for i in res:
     nopol = i [2]
     print(nopol)
```

and the ouput is row formating like this without the bullet

- B 9020 BCS
- B 9243 BQB
- B 9244 BQB
- B 9307 KXR
- B 9552 UXT
- B 9730 BCK
- B 9733 CXS
- B 9746 WRU
- B 9782 FXR

how can i get only one data from mylist
i want get only B 9552 UXT
please help me thanks

i have tried many time but is always fails

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you please give us a code sample that we can use to test it with? You can give us your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your res list look like, but if it is a simple list like this one:

```
res = ['B 9020 BCS', 'B 9243 BQB', 'B 9244 BQB', 'B 9307 KXR', 'B 9552 UXT', 'B 9730 BCK', 'B 9733 CXS' ,'B 9746 WRU', 'B 9782 FXR', 'B 9865 NCG']
```

you can get the single data by its index, like:

```
nopol = res[4]
```

this will return a string in index number 4 which is:

```
'B 9552 UXT'
```

please share what res look like.

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional to your loop, so it only prints the desired element

```
for i in res:
   if i == 'B 9552 UXT':
       print(i)
```

Result:

```
'B 9552 UXT'
```